# Extract the specific data from the JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

```
{
  "msg_id" : "5979ee7c",
  "_text" : "Hello Brother!",
  "entities" : {
    "intent" : [ {
      "confidence" : 0.988721779612267,
      "value" : "greeting"
    } ]
  }
```

How can I get the data of "value" and assign it to my another variable ? Yeah it is a simple thing but I am new to JS.

```
  body = JSON.parse(response.body)
  intent = (body["entities"]["intent"]).value
```

When I tried to do this, it gives me the "undefined" not the real value of "value" .

So how can I initialise the **intent** variable over here ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
intent = (body["entities"]["intent"]).value
```

is supposed to be

```
intent = (body["entities"]["intent"])[0].value
```

As `intent` here is an `Array`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not misunderstanding your question -- you are attempting to access the value at

```
body.entities.intent[0].value
```

I believe that is how you would access the value that you want. JSON.parse returns a javascript object that you can access like an array (I think that's what you were going for) or using dot notation like I did above. There is one tricky part here which is that intent is an array that holds a single object, which is why I needed to use

```
intent[0]
```

before I tried to access value. So the full code in your style would look like:

```
body = JSON.parse(response.body)
intent = body["entities"]["intent"][0].value //no parens needed here
```

I hope this answers your question!